# 'String or binary data truncated' while inserting into SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, passwords

I am trying to create a basic WPF application that can store an encrypted password in SQL Server 2008 and also retrieve back the password when the user tries to login but I am getting an error after following this article

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/123865-one-way-encryption/

I read thru rainbow attacks and salting and hashing..

I tried some code but getting an error

The error I am getting is

> string or binary data would be truncated

I read this article and tried to convert the textbox.text to string and also tried typing only one alphabet in the password texbox but still does not work ("I changed the connstring for security reasons as the connstring is  working and there is no problem with that")

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string strPassword;
        SqlConnection cs= new SqlConnection("Data Source=STEVEJOBS;Initial Catalog=Test database;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Member_info(Name,Username,Password,Email,Member) VALUES(@Name,@Username,@Password,@Email,@Member)", cs);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Name_tb.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email_tb.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Username_tb.Text;

        //MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        //byte[] hashedBytes;
        //UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        //hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strPassword));
        //SqlParameter paramPwd;
        //paramPwd = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.Binary, 16);
        //paramPwd.Value = hashedBytes;
        //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(paramPwd);

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HashPassword(Password_tb.Text.ToString());
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Member", SqlDbType.NText).Value =Myes_rb.Content ;

        cs.Open();

        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully added");
    }

    static string HashPassword(string pasword)
{
           byte[] arrbyte = new byte[pasword.Length];
           SHA256 hash = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
           arrbyte = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pasword));
           return Convert.ToBase64String(arrbyte);
    }
```

Thks for the help!

Comment: Plus, just as note -if you use one way passwords, there is no freaking way to decode them, so you fail already. Even fixing all the buggs n the world wont allow you  to retrieve the pasword. Doing so easily using SHA is getting you a nobel price for mathematics.

Comment: I bet my secret SHA256.unhash() that it is the Password column that throws this error, Base64 uses 3 chars for every 2 input Bytes.

Comment: Think OP wanted to retrieve hashed password and compare it to hashed user input, not to get original password from hashed value from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appears when you try to insert a string with more characters than specified in column definition. Make your string columns wider.

To identify column that triggers this error, You can change your INSERT statement by eliminating parameters one by one (remove `da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add` line for that column and in VALUES part of INSERT statement put a constant like 'John').

EDIT#1:

Continue eliminating columns one by one (just like You did with password column) and once insert statement doesn't fail, You will know what column caused error. Then debug to find out the length of value you are assigning to (failing) column parameter. Length of that column in database must be >= than length of value You are trying to insert.

Another thing to note: at the time of writing your question, You thought that password column is problem, but maybe some other column is problem. **And only solution to this error is to make all columns wide enough so values can be stored in them**.

EDIT#2:

Use [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password.aspx) property to get text user typed in:

```
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
        HashPassword(Password_tb.Password);
```

To get the length of hashed password use this code instead:

```
    string pwdHash = HashPassword(Password_tb.Password);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pwdHash;
```

Put breakpoint on the second line and check the length of pwdHash string. Password column in database table must be equal or greater to this length.

Comment: ok basically figuring from what you said i changed the following sentences    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Member_info(Name,Username,Password,Email,Member) VALUES(@Name,@Username,'jhon',@Email,@Member)", cs);                                                                     and commented out the    //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value; = HashPassword(Password_tb.ToString());   whats your  point?

Comment: You are right, my statement is incomplete in answer, I'll add it right away.

Comment: Hi man i have followed your advice and changed all the columns to just plain values..but when i do that no issues..when i reverse back i mean putting in the @password back i get an error.. The problem is i think in WPF i created this line        <PasswordBox   Height="23"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,133,0,0" Name="Password_tb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  />       so as you can see that it is already a password input..so there is no such thing as 'password.text'..so what to do?

Comment: @JackyBoi, glad to see we are progressing. Take a look at edit#2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are totally off. YOu ahve tons of issues. Lets start:

> I am trying to create a basic WPF application that can store an encrypted password in the SQL 
>   SERVER 2008 and also retrieve back the password when the user try's to login but i am getting an 
>   error after following this article http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/123865-one-way-
>   encryption/

Fail, fired. See, - one way hashing (NOT encryption) is called so because it is one way. NO WAY TO RETRIEVE THE PASSWORD WITHOUT BREAKING IT. Program will never work.

> also tried typing only one alphabet in the password texbox but still doesnot work

Read the documentation how salting works. SHA converts the input into a binary randum number of specific length. It is totally irrelevant whether you feed it 1 or 1000 character long passwords, the result will always be a fixed lengh binary code.

> return Convert.ToBase64String(arrbyte);

This is quite irregular. Most people will convert the arrays into HEX (fixed length, easy to read / write for debugging) and use this.

Anyhow, write out the LENGTH of the string you return here. CHeck all parameters you enter against table structure lengh. Finished.

And you still fail the homework - SHA is not retrievable without breaking.

> basic WPF application that can store an encrypted password in the SQL SERVER 2008 and also 
>   retrieve back the password when the user try's to login

will never be achieved with this approach.

Comment: WOW! that was very detail, tks DONAL TRUMP! haha i am fired! So any articles that i can read and get the right solution after reading thru your detailed report..i hope you do have ..casue i am beatup finding one!

Comment: Sure. Read about encryoption - and stay away from aynthing that is called "one way" ithout hinking what this means when you need two way.

Comment: @TomTom, OP wanted to retrieve hashed password and compare it to hashed user input, not to convert hashed value from database back to original, plain-text password.

Comment: Which incidentally is NOT what he says. I am not in the business of reading the mind of a person expected to be able to express himfself. He explicitly talks of converting back to original password.